# Ploymorphic Association

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Let's say I have these models:

```py
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Users'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    alias = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=False)
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(120), index=False, nullable=True)
    created_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now)
    updated_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now, onupdate=datetime.now)
```

```py
class A(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'A'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
```

```py
class B(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'B'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
```

I want to create another model called Audit that can referentiate `A` and `B`, so I was thinking about polymorphic associations, but I could not find a valid documentation to do that.

```py
class Audit(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'audit'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Users.id'), nullable=True)
    object???
```

I want to have an object that can point to `A` or `B`.

Comment: Can you maybe post an example of the usage you are looking for?  I can't tell exactly what you are asking for.  There is documentation about inheritance where A/B would be interchangeably linked from Audit:  https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/inheritance.html#single-table-inheritance

Comment: So the goal of the auditlog table would be to record an operation executed by a user on an object that can be of type A or B. Example: user 3 deleted object A with Id 2 or user 3 viewed object B with Id 3. Want to have a single column to store those objects.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to guess that maybe you want something like below.  I find that sometimes just columns that are conditionally set is more useful unless you really have an inheritance tree, ie. truly polymorphic models.

```py
class Audit(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'audit'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Users.id'), nullable=True)
    dataset_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('dataset.id'), nullable=True)
    dataset = db.relationship('Dataset', backref='audits')

class Dataset(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'datasets'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String(20))
    name = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on':type,
        # You can probably use None here
        # and set type to nullable= False 
        # if you don't want a base case
        'polymorphic_identity': 'c'
    }

class DatasetA(Dataset):
    info = db.Column(db.String(120))
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'a'
    }

class DatasetB(Dataset):
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'b'
    }
```